# IndentationError in python - what is wrong in my code?

Tags: python, json

```
import requests
import json

url='https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY'    
headers= {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.162 Safari/537.36',
"accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate"} 
def fetch_oi():  
r=requests.get(url,headers=headers).json()
print(r)
with open("oidata.json","w") as files:
    files.write(json.dumps(r,indent=4, sort_keys=True))

def main():
    fetch_oi()


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

** in this code i'm getting error in 
r=requests.get(url,headers=headers).json()
^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

what i'm doing wronge? plzz help

Comment: Well, that line should be indented, as the error message tries really hard to indicate.

Answer (score 3):

The code in a function definition needs to be indented.

```
import json

url='https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY'    
headers= {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.162 Safari/537.36',
"accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate"} 

def fetch_oi():  
    r=requests.get(url,headers=headers).json()
    print(r)
    with open("oidata.json","w") as files:
        files.write(json.dumps(r,indent=4, sort_keys=True))

def main():
    fetch_oi()


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Python depends heavily on correct indentation, see:
https://www.w3schools.in/python-tutorial/concept-of-indentation-in-python/

Answer (score 2):

After your `def fetch_oi():` you are supposed to indent the line `r=requests.get(url,headers=headers).json()` since it is a function

```py
def fetch_oi():  
    r=requests.get(url,headers=headers).json()
    print(r)
```

then depending on where your function ends, you should keep indenting

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is clear that you need

```
def fetch_oi():  
    r=requests.get(url,headers=headers).json()
    print(r)
    with open("oidata.json","w") as files:
        files.write(json.dumps(r,indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

instead of what you have
(that is one tab more in fetch_io).
In python you have to be careful with tabs. You need one identation level after each function.
Take a look here:
https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html

Answer (score 1):

The body of your function `fetch_oi` is unindented.

```
import requests
import json

url='https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY'    
headers= {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.162 Safari/537.36', "accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate"} 

def fetch_oi():  
    r=requests.get(url,headers=headers).json()
    print(r)

    with open("oidata.json","w") as files:
        files.write(json.dumps(r,indent=4, sort_keys=True))

def main():
    fetch_oi()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The `with` block should also be indented.

Answer (score 0):

intend lines after def fetch_oi():

Comment: Can you explain this answer please?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in the body of

```
def fetch_oi():
```

Put space to the body

My suggestions is to use sublime IDE. 
So, when you select the content you can visible the content that you have used space or tab. Also using **tab** is the good approach rather than **space**

I have seen that you have used space. So adjusting and using space will make you troublesome at long run.